# Adding <!--nextpage--> dynamically to WordPress post

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Basically, I'm trying to add the tag `<!--nextpage-->` to generate the pagination of the post dynamically using some shortcode in a plugin,

I've tried to use the following code to do such functionality.

```
public function __construct() {
    add_shortcode('CONTINUED', array(&$this, 'continued_handle'));
}

public function continued_handle() {
    global $post;
    add_filter('the_content', array(&$this, 'your_post_split'));
    return $this->your_post_split($post);
}

public function your_post_split($content) { 
    $output = '<div>In page 1</div>';
    $output .= '<!--nextpage-->';
    $output .= '<div>In page 2</div>';
    return $output;
}
```

When I use the shortcode `[CONTINUED]` on a page, I want it to echo `<div>In page 1</div>` then process the `<!--nextpage-->` like it normally would in WordPress and start the pagination.

What it's actually doing is returning this in the post

```
<div>In page 1</div><!--nextpage--><div>In page 2</div>
```

It's not actually doing the functionality of `<!--nextpage-->` in which I want it to

Comment: The whole code seems wrong and won't do any job

Comment: It seems wrong, but it's not, It's just I don't know how to get the `<!--nextpage-->` to process correctly.

Comment: Surely `<!--nextpage-->` will just render as a HTML comment though?

Comment: yes, that's what it's doing, but if you insert it directly into a WordPress post, it'll render it as pagination

Comment: I did some research. `<!--nextpage-->` is handled by `setup_postdata` and it's the first thing that happens after retrieving the post's content - before any shortcodes are parsed. I can't find any action/filter hook which would allow you to add in an extra `<!--nextpage-->` before that, so I'm afraid you're out of luck here. The only alternative I see is hooking into `the_post` and replicating the page splitting implementation after manually parsing your custom shortcode. Not pretty, so I'm hoping someone else comes up with a better idea.